# NullPointerException on iterating through empty container in java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
public void clearTrash()
{
    for (Email i1 : trash.getEmails()) trash.removeEmail(trash.getEmails().indexOf(i1));
}
```

I thought this would simply return if trash.getEmails() is empty since there is nothing to iterate over, but upon debugging with empty folder it throws NullPointerException. Why doesn't that work?

Comment: Did you check trash object for null?

Comment: Can you please give detailed stack trace? Also, if you can give source of removeEmail(), that would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is logic behind this `foreach` loop, but I'd recommend you use `Iterator` to remove items while iterating, ie:

```
Iterator<Email> it = trash.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    // some logic ....
    it.remove();
}
```

As for your NPE, probably `trash` or maybe `trash.getEmails()` is null. Check for nulls!

Answer (score 0):

Your `trash` var is `null` or the list `trash.getEmails()` is null

So when you use it, its like

```
for(Email i1 : null)
```

Try to get used to evaluate your list before use it:

```
if (trash != null) {
    //some logic here...
    if (trash.getEmails() != null) {
        for(Email i1 : null) {
            //your code...
        }
    }
}
```

Also, as a side note, it would be better in performance to create a new list instead of removing all his elements.

```
//deleting the items in the List<Email>
//maybe the collection is not List, just a supposition, still the idea is the same
trash.setEmails(new List<Email>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Always incorporate [Defensive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) into your code.

Wherever you see an object ,think what to do if it is null and what if it is not null.

like below,you can implement.

```
    if(object==null){
    //doSomething()
    }else{
//doSomethingElse()
    }
```

check if trash is null.

Comment: Instead of else if you can have a else itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use [org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html)

```
 if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(trash.getEmails()){

    //Your logic.
 }
```

isNotEmpty() will check for null as well as empty List.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following thread for a better understanding: [How does a for each loop guard against an empty list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845281/how-does-a-for-each-loop-guard-against-an-empty-list)

In your case the collection trash is **null**. So when you dereference trash you get a null pointer exception. So it is not the empty container which gives you the null pointer exception but rather the dereferencing of trash(null object) which results in null pointer exception.